# After reflecting, I would like to display changes in form page

Tags: laravel

I would like to make a form.
After submitting the data,Redirect to the same page and reflect a change.
I thought return redirect should be a good way.
but it seems need to fetching the DB.
because 'ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:'error happens.

writing   $user = \DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->id)... twice
is redundancy and cheesy.

Is there any good way to implement this.

```
class CertainController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->id)->first();
        $data = ['user' => $user];
        return view('user.detail',$data);
    }
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        \DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $request->id)
        ->update([
        $request->name => $request->value
        ]);
        
        return redirect(route('user.detail', [
            'user_id' => $request->id,
        ]));
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/user_detail', 'CertainController@index')->name('user.detail');
Route::get('/user_detail/update', 'CertainController@update')->name('user.detail.update');
```

blade

```
    <form method ="GET" action={{ route('user.detail.update')}}>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label>name</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="{{ $user->id  }}"/>
            <input type = "hidden" name = "column" value="name">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" required autocomplete="name">

            @error('')
                    {{ $message }}
            @enderror
            <button type = "submit" class ="button">submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `id` in the index method,

```
  $request->id
            ^^
```

But you are sending `user_id` from update method.

```
 'user_id' => $request->id,
  ^^^^^
```

In a simple way, you can just do

```
return back();
```

here, back() is a helper function, which redirect back to where it came from.